# Unable to align <nb-icon> with multi line text

Tags: nebular

I am trying to align an alert-triangle icon with multi line text. Both the text and the icon are supposed to be left-aligned.

[This is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XUeB.png)

[This is what I am able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBl5o.png)

And this is the piece of code I am using:

```
<nb-alert outline="basic" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start;">
                        <div>
                            <div style="float: left;">
                                <nb-icon icon="alert-triangle" status="danger"></nb-icon>
                            </div>
                            <div style="align-self: center; padding:20px; white-space: pre-wrap;" >
                                Error: Error details<br>
                                Explanation: Explanation of Error<br>
                                Status: Status of error<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nb-alert>
```

Can you help me with this... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below CSS code and set the height of the icon that you want.

```html
.nb-theme-default nb-alert {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```